# MS SQL get values after INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, recordset

I am facing an issue where I need to calculate some data based on existing data, then insert that data and finally, return it to an Excel file using VBA.

I have successfully been able to create a stored procedure that returns a table of values after inserting:

```
[...]
INSERT INTO [ExcelRGA] (RM_prefix, RM_suffix, editing, createdBy, editedBy) values (@RM_prefix, @RM_suffix, 1, @user, @user);

DECLARE @tab table (RM varchar(20))

INSERT @tab SELECT (@RM_prefix +'-' + right('00' + @RM_suffix, 3)) as 'RM';

SELECT * FROM @tab  
END
```

and this works! However, I am unable to get the values it is returning using VBA

```
Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Dim objRec As Object
cmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.newRM"

cmd.Parameters.Refresh
cmd.Parameters("@user").Value = "john"

Set oRS = cmd.Execute()
```

but I try to do something like

```
while not oRS.eof
   ....
wend
```

get an error message stating that the recordset is closed and I cannot do my thing.

All I am trying to do is secure the information that I have computed (RM_prefix and RM_suffix), insert them into my table and return them to my Excel file.

If there is a way to do this without using a store procedure (such as a function) that would also be great!

Please keep in mind that this is a multi-user environment, so generating the values in Excel, sending them to the SQL server for an insert doesn't give a 100% guarantee regarding the uniqueness of said data.

Thank you all for your precious help and inputs!

Peter

Comment: In your code, `oRS` is the name you give to the Recordset, but in the `while` code, you refer `rs`. Is that a mistake?

Comment: sorry,yes. It is actually oRS

Comment: What happens if you use a temporary table instead of a table variable?

Comment: that could be an option, but how can I make sure that I am getting in Excel the value that I've inserted? The only parameter that is passed from Excel is the username. However, it can happen that two different persons use the same account.

Comment: Add `oRs.MoveFirst` before while loop, you can also use `oRs.Open 'SqlCommandHere'` instead of `.Execute`

Comment: I tried adding `oRS.open` so it's like:

`Set oRS = cmd.Execute()
        
        oRS.Open
        
        While Not oRS.EOF
            oRS.MoveNext
        Wend`

But it is still says that the object is closed.

Comment: you cannot use oRs.Open with .Execute, use oRs.MoveFirst before while loop and not inside, Ex: `Set oRS = cmd.Execute() oRs.MoveFirst While Not oRS.EOF ... wend`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've done it exactly like you said and it still says "operation is not allowed when object is closes" (run time err 3704) on `oRS.MoveFirst`.   If it Helps, I'm using `ADODB.RecordSet` for `oRS` and `ADODB.Command` for `cmd`.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the issue was coming from the SQL Stored Procedure. I've added 
     `SET NOCOUNT ON;`
right before the
    `INSERT INTO [ExcelRGA] (RM_prefix, RM_suffix, editing, createdBy, editedBy) values (@RM_prefix, @RM_suffix, 1, @user, @user);`

And it has solved my problem! I can now browse the recordset in VBA.

Thank you all for your help and inputs!

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this -

```
Private Function GetIDENTITY() As Long

oRS.Open "SELECT @@identity AS NewID", oCon


If Not IsNull(oRS.Fields("NewID")) Then

    GetIDENTITY = oRS.Fields("NewID"): oRS.Close

Else

    MsgBox "Error: Identity value not returned.", vbCritical

    End

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! But where am I supposed to insert this? I've tried running it right after the `cmd.Execute()` but I got the Critical.